# TailwindCSS Phone breakpoint overflow-x problem

Tags: css

I have a problem with one of my projects where I use `TailwindCSS`.
The page looks all right on Desktop, Tablet and some phones, but for some of them, the website has a horizontal scrollbar.
This problem is only happening on Google Chrome on iOS (iPhone 11 Pro).

- On iPhone 5 everything looks fine; no horizontal scrollbar.
- On Safari the website looks alright on all devices (mobile, tablet,
  desktop).

I've done something wrong, because I can't figure out what's happened.

The problem can be found [here](https://pantazisoft.com/)

P.S.: I added `overflow-x-hidden` on body to prevent the scrollbar, but didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, it would be helpful to include your code here. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/AnwQp1sVue Here i included a part of the code, don't know if this is the problem, can't figure it out. This is why i attached the link to the entire website. 

I added this image to get an ideea - https://imgur.com/a/2UfJJ3y

Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841872/horizontal-scrollbar-showing-even-when-overflow-is-hidden?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found the problem, is realated to `aos.js` library that i have loaded for animation on div's elements. On mobile the library creates a "side space", after i deleted the animation, everything looks ok.

Thank you!